Horror movie about novelist?
I seen this film when I was a child so I may not be spot on with detail/plot. I've been searching for a psychological horror movie (around the era 90s) as follows:
It is about a novelist who I believe loses his son in a fire. He moves into a house haunted by evil(?) spirits. One spirit being a girl who shot herself in the head an I believe died in the house. I believe he may be writing a book about the house. The man begins to go crazy and have flashbacks of his son (I think).
The movie in color, looks like it was made in either 80s or 90s. The film  is very creepy.

can't add an answer because this has been closed, but it sounds like the movie "House" from 1985, starring William Katt, George Went and Bull Shannon from nightcourt.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWcZTEo3jmw
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091223/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2

I strongly think your are talking about the movie 1408.

Mike Enslin is a cynical, skeptical author who is estranged from his wife Lily after the death of their daughter Katie.
Mike writes unsuccessful books evaluating supernatural events in which he has no belief.
Mike receives an anonymous postcard, a hotel on Lexington Avenue in New York City bearing the message, "Don't enter 1408." Viewing this as a challenge, Mike forces the hotel to allow him to book the room.
Once inside the room,He begins to see hallucinations and ghosts of the room's past victims, and visions of his own dead family members, including his father and Katie.

In your question you said about his son, but in here its really his daughter.

i actually thought of the same movie, but the question description seemed too contrasting to 1408
